# How to represent direction in a route in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

In a project I'm displaying a route using `PolylineOptions` for drawing rects from one POI to the next POI.

Also in each POI I'm drawing a circle.

The objective is to represent the direction of the route in some way, for example, drawing an arrow in the middle of each `PolylineOptions` rect. The problem is that I can't find how to do this.

This is my code:

```
    PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    float[] prevHSV = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), prevHSV);
    rectOptions.color(Color.HSVToColor(255, prevHSV));

    String[][] routeInformation = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getLineInformation(line);
    ArrayList<Double[]> routeStops = Util.getFullRouteFromLine(this, line);
    final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    for (int i=0; i<routeInformation.length; i++){
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(routeInformation[i][0]),Double.parseDouble(routeInformation[i][1]));
        builder.include(latlng);
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latlng).radius(15).strokeColor(Color.HSVToColor(255, prevHSV)).fillColor(Color.HSVToColor(255, prevHSV)).zIndex(7777));            
    }

    for (Double[] pos : routeStops){
        rectOptions.add(new LatLng(pos[0],pos[1])).width(5);
    }
    mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Is there a easy way to represent the direction of a route?

Something similar to this, but this is for the web version of google maps, not for the android version: http://jsfiddle.net/nX8U8/2/

Answer (score 2):

IMHO easiest way is to use flat "north-oriented" direction marker (arrow) like that:

[image: Direction marker]

created via vector drawable `ic_arrow_up.xml`:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportHeight="560"
    android:viewportWidth="560"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    >
    <path android:fillColor="#0000FF"
        android:pathData="M0,559.43C0,557.943 279.994,-0.561 280.458,0C282.014,1.884 560.512,559.569 559.999,559.776C559.665,559.911 496.562,532.823 419.77,499.581C419.77,499.581 280.15,439.14 280.15,439.14C280.15,439.14 140.756,499.57 140.756,499.57C64.089,532.807 1.056,560 0.681,560C0.307,560 0,559.743 0,559.43C0,559.43 0,559.43 0,559.43Z"
    />
</vector>
```

placed on each path polyline segment middle point with angle calculated on segment bearing. Both polyline segment middle and bearing you can determine via [`SphericalUtil`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html) class of [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/) . Bearing can be found via [`SphericalUtil.computeHeading()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeHeading-LatLng-LatLng-) with first and second points of segment as arguments and `LatLng` of segment middle point - via [`SphericalUtil.interpolate()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#interpolate-LatLng-LatLng-double-) also with first and second points of segment as arguments `from` and `to` and constant 0.5 (half) as `fraction` argument.

So, with source like this:

```
...
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            List<LatLng> sourcePoints = new ArrayList<>();
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions;

            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.27801,149.12958));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28032,149.12907));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28099,149.12929));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28144,149.12984));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28194,149.13003));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28282,149.12956));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28302,149.12881));
            sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(-35.28473,149.12836));

            polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyLineOptions.addAll(sourcePoints);
            polyLineOptions.width(10);
            polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sourcePoints.get(0), 15));

            for (int i = 0; i < sourcePoints.size() - 1; i++) {
                // get first and second points of polyline segment
                LatLng segmentP1 = sourcePoints.get(i);
                LatLng segmentP2 = sourcePoints.get(i+1);

                // calculate middle point
                LatLng segmentMiddlePoint = SphericalUtil.interpolate(segmentP1, segmentP2, 0.5);
                // calculate bearing
                float segmentBearing = (float) SphericalUtil.computeHeading(segmentP1, segmentP2);

                // add flat marker at segment middle
                addDirectionMarker(segmentMiddlePoint, segmentBearing);
            }

    });

}
...
public void addDirectionMarker(LatLng latLng, float angle) {
    Drawable circleDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_up);
    BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable, 30, 30);

    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .rotation(angle)
            .flat(true)
            .icon(markerIcon)
    );
}
```

you'll got something like that:

[image: Path with direction markers]

Also you can change size of arrows markers by set other values than `30, 30` in

`BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable, 30, 30);`

line.